# Find and print specific strings from xml based on search for father leaf string

Tags: xml, linux, bash, awk, sed

I need to extract all FCP names from xml file, based on collector name on CentOS server
The amount of lines inside CPM tag is unknown
Preferable bash, but fine with any solution.

Example: input file

```
  <CPM display_name="XYZ"  collector="202a" >
    <FCP name="a1" second_name="b2"/>
    <FCP name="a3" second_name="b232323"/>
    <FCP name="a2" second_name="b445"/>
  </CMP>
  <CPM display_name="XYZ"  collector="204a" >
    <FCP name="z1" second_name="b232323232"/>
    <FCP name="s3" second_name="b23232323"/>
    <FCP name="t2" second_name="b4453223"/>
  </CMP>
  <CPM display_name="XYZ"  collector="202a" >
    <FCP name="a11" second_name="basdasdasdasd2"/>
  </CMP>
```

....
Long file of more than 500 lines.

Expected output

```
collector="202a"
name="a1"
name="a2"
name="a3"
name="a11"

collector="204a"
name="z1"
name="s3"
name="t2
```

"

Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Did you try anything?  What didn't work?

Comment: Don't use line-oriented tools to process XML. Use something like `xsltproc` instead.

Comment: Why are your opening and closing tags different? `CPM` and `CMP`?

Answer (score 2):

A `gawk` solution, with `match`, `substr`, `RSTART` and  `RLENGTH` you can emulate `grep -o` behaviour, and `A[length(A)+1]=N` emulate array push behaviour:

```
awk '
    match($0, /collector="[^"]*"/){
        collector=substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
    }
    match($0,/[ ]name="[^"]*"/) {
        d[collector][length(d[collector])+1]=substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH)
    }
    END{
        for(k in d){ 
            print(k)
            for (i in d[k]) print d[k][i]
            print ""
        }
    }' file
```

**EDIT: Thanks, Ed Morton**

```
awk '
    match($0, /\<collector="[^"]*"/, a){ collector=a[0] } 
    match($0, /\<name="[^"]*"/, a){ d[collector][length(d[collector])+1]=a[0] }
    END{
        for(k in d){ 
            print(k)
            for (i in d[k]) print d[k][i]
            print ""
        }
    }' file
```

you get,

```
collector="202a"
name="a1" 
name="a3" 
name="a2" 
name="a11" 

collector="204a"
name="z1" 
name="s3" 
name="t2"
```

**bonus:** A non `gawk` solution, `sed`, `grep`, `sort` and `tr` functions

```
grep -oE '\b(collector|name)="[^"]*"' file | 
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\nname/ name/g' | 
sort -k1 | 
sed ':a;$!N;/^\([^ ]*[ ]\).*\n\1/s/\n/ /;ta;P;D' | 
sed 's/[ ]collector="[^"]*"//g' | 
tr ' ' '\n'
```

you get,

```
collector="202a"
name="a11"
name="a1"
name="a3"
name="a2"
collector="204a"
name="z1"
name="s3"
name="t2"
```